# PostgreSQL How to convert JSONB array of arrays to pg array of arrays?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb, pg

I have `options` JSONB field:

[image]

And I can get JSONB array:

```
SELECT "options" FROM "products";
```

->

```
'[["black", "2"], ["white", "7"]]'::JSONB
```

But, How can I make array of arrays?

->

```
ARRAY[ARRAY['black', '2'], ARRAY['white', '7']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (
  select array_agg(
    (select array_agg(s) from jsonb_array_elements_text(a) j2(s))
  ) from jsonb_array_elements(options) j1(a)
) from products
```